# Tensorflow.js: expandDims() + cast() issue

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I need to provide a `float32` tensor for my model. I need to use `expandDims(tensor, axis=0)` to change its shape from `[240, 320, 3]` to `[1, 240, 320, 3]`. However, it appears that the `expandDims()` operation casts my tensor to `int32`.

When I perform `cast(tensor, "float32")` on this tensor, it appears that the `cast` operation squeezes my tensor back to `[240, 320, 3]`.

```
image_v = (tf.cast(image_raw, "float32") / 255.0) - 0.5;
image_v = tf.expandDims(image_raw, 0); 
console.log(image_v.shape) // shape: [1, 240, 320, 3]
console.log(image_v.dtype) // dtype: "int32"

image_v = tf.cast(image_raw, "float32") 
console.log(image_v.shape) // shape: [240, 320, 3]
console.log(image_v.dtype) // dtype: "float32"
```

I am looking for a way to expand dims on a `float32` tensor in `tensorflow.js` and have the tensor's `dtype` remain `float32`. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess this is a typo? You are casting your original tensor (`image_raw`) and not your created expanded tensor (`image_v`).

Comment: This may have been the problem, actually! Gonna check it now.

Comment: Also added a "long version" answer as you also made another (minor) mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to think, that operations like `tf.cast` work on the original tensor. But that is not the case. To quote the docs:

> A tf.Tensor object represents an immutable, multidimensional array of numbers that has a shape and a data type.

That means, whenever you call a function like `tf.cast` or `tf.expandDims` a new tensor is created. Therefore, your `tf.cast(image_raw, "float32")` call will not change the original tensor, but create a new one.

**Solution**

To cast your tensor, you should use `image_v` instead of `image_raw` as the latter tensor was never changed.

```js
image_v = tf.cast(image_raw, "float32");
```

Also, the beginning of your script is not working for another reason (which is not responsible for the problem you are facing, though). Normal JavaScript operations do not work on tensors. Check out [`tf.div`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#div) and [`tf.sub`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#sub) instead.

So, all in all, your code should look like this:

```js
image_v = tf.cast(image_raw, "float32").div(255).sub(0.5);
image_v = tf.expandDims(image_v, 0);
console.log(image_v.shape) // should now be: [1, 240, 320, 3]
console.log(image_v.dtype) // and this should be: dtype: "int32"
```

Like the other answer already suggested, you should also check out [`tf.tidy`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tidy) to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you! I believe I made a mistake with the whole image_raw, image_v thing. I am aware that the tensor cast produces a new tensor, but I was not aware of the memory issues. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Tfjs can't use JS operations on tensors, you have to use `tf.div()` and `tf.sub()`.

> image_v = (tf.cast(image_raw, "float32") / 255.0) - 0.5;

`image_v` is now `NaN`, because `({}/255)-0.5 === NaN`

> image_v = tf.expandDims(image_raw, 0);

Now you expand the original image, wich wasn't modified.

> image_v = tf.cast(image_raw, "float32")

You reused the original `image_raw`, because in tf operations don't modify the tensor. They always create a new one.

And I recommend don't reusing variables or working outside [`tf.tidy()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tidy), because you can easily forget to `.dispose()` and thus creating a memory leak.

```js
const image_raw = tf.zeros([240, 320, 3]);

const modified = tf.tidy(() => {
  const image_v_casted = tf.cast(image_raw, "float32").div(255).sub(0.5);
  const image_v_expanded = tf.expandDims(image_v_casted, 0);

  return image_v_expanded;
});


console.log('shape', modified.shape);
console.log('dtype', modified.dtype);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: IMHO, this is wrong. He is not expanding `image_v`, but `image_raw`. Therefore, he is never expanding `NaN`.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Tried it with my modified code